# client and server wrong output

Tags: python-3.x, client-server

I am having trouble trying to receive packet from the client and it is not doing what I want it to do. I do not know what is the problem. Can someone tell me something that I not seeing here

```
with open("PROJI-HNS.txt", "r") as fp:
    with open('HW2out.txt','w') as fw:
        while True: 
            # print(tokens)
            tokens = fp.readline().lower()
            domains = tokens.strip()
            if not tokens:
                break
            print(str(domains))
            # send the tokens   
            rc.sendall(str(domains).encode('utf-8'))
```

This is just fine. It is doing what I want it to do.

```
kill.cs.rutgers.edu
mx.rutgers.com
www.ibm.edu
google.com
www.google.com
mx.rutgers.edu
```

But the problem is on the server side and is what I need help with.

```
while True:
    conn, address = sc.accept()
    client_host = ' '
    while client_host != "":
        client_host = conn.recv(200).decode('utf-8')
        if not client_host:
            break; 
        print(f"[C] Client looking for: {client_host}")
```

This is where I am receiving the packets and this is where the problem occurs, well just not printing the right output I want. which is how I send packet through the client and thats how I want the server to receive to move forward to do my next task. If I can fix this then I can do the rest. I just need to get the right packet as a string. Can someone see what is the problem. Any more code you need to see let me know. I am happy to show it.

This is the what the server output:

```
[C] Client looking for: mx.rutgers.edu
[C] Client looking for: kill.cs.rutgers.edu
[C] Client looking for: mx.rutgers.comwww.ibm.edugoogl
[C] Client looking for: e.comwww.google.commx.rutgers.
[C] Client looking for: edu
[C] Client looking for: kill.cs.rutgers.edumx.rutgers.
[C] Client looking for: comwww.ibm.edugoogle.comwww.go
[C] Client looking for: ogle.commx.rutgers.edu
[C] Client looking for: kill.cs.rutgers.edumx.rutgers.
[C] Client looking for: comwww.ibm.edugoogle.comwww.go
[C] Client looking for: ogle.commx.rutgers.edu
[C] Client looking for: kill.cs.rutgers.edumx.rutgers.
[C] Client looking for: comwww.ibm.edugoogle.comwww.go
[C] Client looking for: ogle.commx.rutgers.edu
[C] Client looking for: kill.cs.rutgers.edu
[C] Client looking for: mx.rutgers.comwww.ibm.edugoogl
[C] Client looking for: e.comwww.google.commx.rutgers.
[C] Client looking for: edu
[C] Client looking for: kill.cs.rutgers.edumx.rutgers.
[C] Client looking for: comwww.ibm.edugoogle.comwww.go
[C] Client looking for: ogle.commx.rutgers.edu
```

That is not I want the server to receive. I want to see what the client is sending one by one to move forward with I am trying to do 
and I can not seem to get this done. Well I just dont know what I am not seeing here.

Comment: Why did you decide to tag it with Python 3 and Python 2.7?

Comment: IDK if people have updated themselves to python3. But I got rid of it.